# Start a guest domain libvirt

Tags: java, qemu, libvirt

How can I start a guest domain using libvirt java api .

I have a guest machine which is currently powered off .How can i power on

that machine using libvirt java api .Below is my code for the same

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/power/{vmName}", produces = { "application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity updatePower(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("vmName") String vmName) throws LibvirtException {
        ResponseEntity resp = null;

        Connect conn = Connection.getConnection();

        Domain machine=conn.domainLookupByName(vmName);

        if(machine.isActive()==1){
            machine.shutdown();
        }else{
            //I need to start my guest domain here if its inactive.
        }


        return resp;
    }
```

Comment: i am afraid, there is no method like `start()` in `Domain`, but you have a option to `resume`

Comment: @piyushjaiswal does domain.create() start the guestmachine?

Comment: no it will create a new `guestmachine`, but wont be able to able start the start existing ones .....